# Pandas Dataframe: get a multiindex row above the current column headings and merge the cells into a single cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to use pandas dataframe to add a a row above the current column heading. The first row should be a singly-merged cell that contains today's date.

My current dataframe looks like below

```
index   name   field1    field2
  1     John    blah      blah
  2     Dave    blah      blah
  .........
```

But I'm trying to make the dataframe to look like this:

```
 T  O  D  A  Y \' s   D  A  T  E 
index   name   field1    field2
  1     John    blah      blah
  2     Dave    blah      blah
  .........
```

I hear you can use `pd.multiindex.`..but can't seem to get a grip of this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("Today's date", field) for field in df.colums])
```

ought to work.

Note what this does: it is not possible to merge a cell in pandas. It's just that repeated values don't get shown in this case.

If your goal is to concatenate several of these guys, I would suggest using a dictionary:

```
pd.concat({"Yesteday's date": yesterday_df, "Today's date": today_df}, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is set `column name`, then `MultiIndex` is not necessary:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John','Dave'],
                   'field1':['blah','blah'],
                   'field2':['blah','blah']},
                    index=[1,2],
                    columns=['name','field1','field2'])

print (df)
   name field1 field2
1  John   blah   blah
2  Dave   blah   blah

#get today date
today = pd.to_datetime('now').date()

#pandas version 018.0 and more
df = df.rename_axis(today,axis=1)
#pandas verion below 0.18.0
#df.columns.name = today
print (df)
2016-08-11  name field1 field2
1           John   blah   blah
2           Dave   blah   blah

#if need remove column name
df = df.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print (df)
   name field1 field2
1  John   blah   blah
2  Dave   blah   blah
```